# ag-grid Infinite Scroll Top

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Yes, this is kind of a general question, no I don't have a code example, but I'm still looking for an answer :)

I'm trying to use ag-grid with Angular and need to be able to do infinite scroll in a way that it triggers the call for data when the grid is at the **top** not the bottom.  My data is structured so that the newest info is on the bottom, so scrolling up should call for more data.  The data does not support the obvious solution of *Why don't you just put the new data at the top?*.

Does anyone have experience doing this with ag-grid?

Answer (score 0):

> This is not the exact answer you'd be looking for, but I'm sure you will get some help `OR` some approach `OR` out of the box idea. I guess even people from [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) wouldn't have though of such approach.
>
> Its just a prototype. You can use this example to make it work with infinite scrolling, but it would be just like a normal one.

Have a look at [this plunk I've created](https://plnkr.co/edit/zIZgMb41JWLVU331sOwr?p=preview)

I've enabled a flag `[enableRtl]="true"`

Added below CSS

```
.ag-body-viewport, .ag-cell, .ag-header, .ag-header-cell {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Still you'd have to do lots of things, like ellipses, scroll direction is reverse wrt mouse wheel, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. ui-grid has this as an optional parameter out of the box, so I was hoping ag-grid had something similar.